# Phonegap Android app closes unexpectedly in 1.5

Tags: android, cordova

I am building a really small Android app with Phonegap (it's just an interactive animation of a weiner dog....). The app works fine on my phone (2.3.5) . Now I built a clone of the project and reduced the minimum SDK to 3 (which would be Android 1.5). The app still runs perfectly on my phone, yet when I launch a 1.5 AVD or try to install it on a 1.5 phone it crashes on startup ('The application closed unexpectedly').

I have found some information on this topic on the web, but it all dates back to early 2010 and states that this is a Phonegap bug that should be resolved by now.

Phone-APIs I am using in my app are sound (`Media`) and detecting if the app is visible (
`Events`).

My `manifest.xml`looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.me.weinerDog"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".WeinerDogActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter></intent-filter>          
        </activity>
     </application>

</manifest>
```

The `plugins.xml`in `res\xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="com.phonegap.App"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="com.phonegap.GeoBroker"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="com.phonegap.Device"/>
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="com.phonegap.AccelListener"/>
    <plugin name="Compass" value="com.phonegap.CompassListener"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="com.phonegap.AudioHandler"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="com.phonegap.CameraLauncher"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="com.phonegap.ContactManager"/>
    <plugin name="Crypto" value="com.phonegap.CryptoHandler"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="com.phonegap.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="Network Status" value="com.phonegap.NetworkManager"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="com.phonegap.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="com.phonegap.Storage"/>
    <plugin name="Temperature" value="com.phonegap.TempListener"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="com.phonegap.FileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="com.phonegap.Capture"/>
</plugins>
```

When running in an AVD the Eclipse console won't report any errors on crash.
Anyone encountered this recently? I am using Phonegap 1.4.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched and it says that phongap needs a minimum sdk of 7 [Android 2.1] to run probaply

it's kind of strange....
that it works on the device

Comment: Where did you read this? Here it even uses a 1.6 demo screen: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494774/Getting%20started%20with%20Android%20PhoneGap%20in%20Eclipse

Comment: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap%20Eclipse%20PlugIn%20for%20Android

Comment: I forgott every phonegap version above 1.0

Comment: Ok, this might explain a lot... Maybe they shouldn't hide it in the fine print and mention it in the "Getting started guide" then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think some of the plugins need 2.2
try to delete the plugins which are not needed

Comment: I tried boiling it down to `App`,`Device`and `Media`, still no difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

When PhoneGap made its 1.0 release, it removed support for pre-Android 2.1 SDKs. If you want to support Android 1.5 or 1.6, you need to go back to one of the PhoneGap 0.9*'s.